# Compile Error "End With without With"

Tags: vba, excel

For the code below, I keep getting the Compile Error: "End With without With"

```
Sub Copy_Swivel_To_MIM_DATA()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Swivel")
        .Columns("AC:AC").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("A1")
        .Columns("J:J").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("B1")
        .Columns("K:K").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("C1")
        .Columns("L:L").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("D1")
        .Columns("M:M").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("E1")
        .Columns("N:N").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("F1")
        .Columns("O:O").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("G1")
        .Columns("P:P").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("H1")
        .Columns("Q:Q").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("I1")
        .Columns("F:F").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Sheets("MIM Data").Range("J1")
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MIM Data")
        .Columns("A:J").EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MIM Data").Sort
        With .SortFields
            .Clear
            .Add Key:=Range("A2:A2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("G2:G2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("B2:B2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("C2:C2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("D2:D2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .Add Key:=Range("E2:E2000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        .SetRange Range("A2:AE2000")
        .Apply
    End With

    Worksheets("MIM QA").Columns("A:J").AutoFit

    With Sheets("MIM Data").Range("A2:AA2000")
        With .Font
            .name = "Arial"
            .FontStyle = "Regular"
            .Size = 10
            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
        End With
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MIM Data")

        Dim DelAftDis As Long
        For DelAftDis = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

        With Cells(DelAftDis, 10)
        If .Value = "After Dispute For SBU" Then
            Rows(DelAftDis).EntireRow.Delete
        End With

        Next DelAftDis

    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select

End Sub
```

I do not understand the error message as each `With` has an associated `End With`. The lines that are indicated as the issue are these:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("MIM Data")

        Dim DelAftDis As Long
        For DelAftDis = Cells(Rows.Count, 10).End(xlUp).row To 2 Step -1

        With Cells(DelAftDis, 10)
        If .Value = "After Dispute For SBU" Then
            Rows(DelAftDis).EntireRow.Delete
        End With ' <--- This is highlighted by the debugger

        Next DelAftDis

    End With
```

Am I missing a `With` or an `End With`? If so, where should it be placed?

Comment: You are missing an End IF for this IF `If .Value = "After Dispute For SBU" Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner Ok. Thanks. That worked. But why is VBA telling me it is a problem with the `With` statement?

Comment: It sees those End Withs in the IF Statement, so when looking it can't find the End with for the With Statement before and it is the first error.  If you had not been using With Blocks it would have correctly found the missing End If.

Comment: @ScottCraner Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. You should put this as an answer for others to see. Will help for future reference for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be missing an "End if" for the line of code:

```
If .Value = "After Dispute For SBU" Then
```

Just add an "End if" at the end as follows:

```
With Cells(DelAftDis, 10)
        If .Value = "After Dispute For SBU" Then
            Rows(DelAftDis).EntireRow.Delete
        End if
End With
```